# Concave-Convex Decomposition of a continuous function

Tags: calculus, convex-optimization

In this paper http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~yuille/pubs/optimize_papers/cccp_nips01.pdf they have a theorem that says that a twice continuous differentiable function (an energy function, they say) with bounded Hessian can always be decomposed as a sum of a concave part and convex part. 
However, I am not able to see how one can decompose sin[x] in the interval $[0,4\pi]$. I have come up with a maybe incorrect solution 
$sin[x]=fcave+fvex$, with $fcave=1000\pi x^2$ and $fvex=sin[x]-1000\pi x^2$, with $fvex''=-sin[x]-2000\pi$ that is negative in all the reals. Is this correct, I am not convinced yet, can you tell me if sin[x] can be decomposed in this way indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure:
$$ \sin x = \sin^+(x)+\sin^-(x) = \max(0,\sin x)+\min(0,\sin x) \tag{1}$$
and now we just have to integrate *twice* the previous line to decompose $\sin x$ as a sum of a convex and a concave function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what about the kinks of the function, around them the $max(0,sinx)$ looks concave, should I mollify the function (smoothed around the kinks)?

Comment: @user157623: Convex does not imply smooth (just consider $f(x)=|x|$). Anyway, since $\max(0,\sin x)$ is continuous, when integrating it twice we get a $C^2$ function for sure.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the mistake